# SQL QUERY - Select a value directly from the database

Tags: php, database, options

In my WordPress database, in the `options` table, there is a field in the `option_name` column which is called `titb_flc_options`, whose value is this:

```
s:397:"a:10:{
    s:16:"69c3d01e88aba503";
    s:0:"";
    s:12:"titb_flc_url";
    s:34:"https://www.facebook.com/wired/";
    s:17:"titb_flc_btnlabel";
    s:15:"Chiedi al guru!";
    s:18:"titb_flc_titlesize";
    s:4:"true";
    s:17:"titb_flc_language";
    s:5:"it_IT";
    s:16:"a65a212aa62e5e30";
    s:0:"";
    s:11:"button_icon";
    s:15:"003-messenger-1";
    s:11:"button_size";
    s:10:"flc_medium";
    :15:"button_position";
    s:5:"right";
    s:14:"button_animate";
    s:1:"1";
}";
```

How do I select the value, for example: `https://www.facebook.com/wired/` to display it on the screen?

Comment: Is there a reason you’re using an SQL query instead of just `get_option()`?

Comment: The value contained in the database is the remnant of an old framework, in fact if I try to use get_option () it returns me a string(397), instead I have to retrieve the individual values of the array. I hope I have explained...

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the answer to my question, the audience in case it might be of help to someone else:

```
$risultato =  maybe_unserialize(get_option('titb_flc_options'));    
echo $risultato['titb_flc_url'];
```

Comment: Welcome to wpse! that is strange, `get_option` should unserialize by default, it uses [maybe_unserialize](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_unserialize/) so im guessing it diden't consider that data as serialized, even though it looks serialized.

Comment: It seems to have been double serialized.

Comment: As I said above, this value is the remnant of an old framework (Titan Framework) that perhaps it stored the data in a particular way... 
If I tried to use get_option ('titb_flc_url') I got "warning: illegal string offset"